# Scope needed for getAttachments?

Tags: gmail-addons

In a Gmail Add-on, this line:

```
var attachments = message.getAttachments();
```

fails with a message `Access denied: : Not allowed for full access to mail message.`

The `appscripts.json` manifest file contains:

```
"oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"
]
```

What else is needed?  I've not found any mention of which scope is required for `getAttachments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include this
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly" 
and remove these 2:

"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action"

This works for me.

Comment: In my experiments to get this working, I missed the obvious combination!